# How to display EBTD , EBIT have same value and EBTN,EBTG have same values using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have taken df1= [EBTD,EBTN] and df2= [EBIT,EBTG]

i have to show as per year, EBTD value == EBIT value & EBTN value ==EBTG value.

and print the message like "EBTD == EBIT and EBTN ==EBTG".

both condition should be passed.

df1

```
    tag    Year              Value                series_id
0  EBTD  2019/03/31          61847                   0
1  EBTD  2019/06/30          61847                   0
2  EBTN  2019/03/31          61847248                0
3  EBTN  2019/06/30          61847248                0
```

df2

```
    tag      Year       Value      series_id
0  EBIT  2019/03/31     61847        0
1  EBIT  2019/06/30     61847        0
2  EBTG  2019/03/31     61847248     0
3  EBTG  2019/06/30     61847248     0
```

My written code:

```
 merged_df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['year'],how='inner')
 years=[]
 for ind,row in merged_df.iterrows():
     if row['value_x'] == row['value_y']:
                years.append(row['year'])               
     print("EBTD == EBIT and EBTN ==EBTG")
```

but i am not getting result

Comment: in question (not in comment) show also expected result.

Comment: EBTD value == EBIT value & EBTN value ==EBTG value.                                                    i don't want expected result....just want to print message when this situation occure

Comment: if you need it on any date then use normal for-loop and compare values row by row. If you want to compare values for the same date then you could join both dataframes into one dataframe and later work with `.groupby('Year')`

Comment: getting error as "'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'replace'"

Comment: I can't see your code, and I can't read in your mind - I have no idea what you are doing. You have to show all details in question. And it would be good if you would create `minimal working code` with example data in code - so we could simply copy and test it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Year'],how='inner')                                                                    df = df.groupby('Year')['Value']                                                                                                 for ind,row in df.iterrows():
            if (row['value_x'] == row['value_y']):                                                                       
                   print("EBTD == EBIT and EBTN ==EBTG")

Comment: df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Year'],how='inner') 
df = df.groupby('Year')['Value'] 
for ind,row in df.iterrows(): 
      if (row['value_x'] == row['value_y']): print("EBTD == EBIT and EBTN ==EBTG")